# Run maven building profile without building, just run exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I created 4 run profiles that contain only the maven-exec plugin with goal java to run my war with different startup parameters. Problem is that profiles are always triggering rebuilding my war file, and it causes failure because the war file is in use when at least one of these profiles is already running. I don't want to rebuild war when I run these profiles. Is it possible to run the build profile without building war and just run the plugins in the profile?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>devAdmin</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-admin</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devCluster</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-cluster</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devClient</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-client</argument>
                        </arguments>
                       ...
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devWeb</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-web</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: Try to execute just the single goal `mvn exec:java -PdevClient`

Answer (score 0):

Execute just the single goal: `mvn exec:java -PdevClient`